# Certain IPs cannot connect to SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, linux-networking, ping

So recently a server's Public IP changed, which meant other servers that connected to it needed to be corrected so that they can connect again. Now the weird thing is I can connect to the new server via SSH and I can ping it, but from two servers it's like that IP does not even exist. It never completes a ping and the SSH connection gets stuck at `Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx`.

I know I can access the server because I am connected to it via SSH (not on the same network). I know other servers can connect to it. But why can't those two servers even ping that IP?

Regard!

Answer (score 2):

From the symptoms you've described ("stuck at `Connecting to...`"; can ping from one source, but not from others), my primary suspicion is that a firewall `DENY` rule is causing the target server to ignore data coming from the non-working servers or, if the firewall rule is on an intermediate router, the data may not even be reaching the target server at all.

Comment: I am not using UFW for the server. A network firewall or VPC firewall, idk the correct term. It currently allows all IPs to access the SSH port. So it isnt a firewall rule. was the third thing i checked, should have added it my question. my bad.

Comment: @echo_salik It isn't a firewall rule on your end. Did you check the other end?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yep. On both end. No firewall rules that block those IPs.